# Is it possible to export my MediaMonkey playlists in Itunes?

Tags: itunes, export, playlists, mediamonkey

I am using both softwares but I would like to import MediaMonkey's playlist in Itunes.
Can you tell me how to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

Select the playlist name in MediaMonkey, then go to File > Export to Playlist.

Save the playlist, and then in iTunes, go to File > Library > Import Playlists and select the playlist you just saved.

Your playlist should now be imported into iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using MediaMonkey 3.2.4.1304 and iTunes 10.4.0.80 and the solution which @Jazzy Josh described didn't work for me. Whenever I imported the M3U playlist in iTunes it was empty, althought the playlist-file looked correct to me.

What worked for me was just selecting all files in the playlist within MediaMonkey and dragging them over onto the empty playlist in iTunes. I had imported the whole library into iTunes previously and dragging the lists over did not create any duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Chiming in late, but: There is an [iTunes plugin](http://www.mediamonkey.com/wiki/index.php/ITunes_Plugin_Info) for MediaMonkey that makes your iTunes install look like a device.

"> Synchronise MM playlist folders to iPods"

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can right click on your iPod and go to Properties for the device.

Once there you can tell it what you want to sync: playlists, podcasts, etc.  Just choose the playlist you want to sync and it will sync it for you.